# How to make counter unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, gui, text

How do I count how many diamonds my player has collected in my 3d world

What I need to do is to make a script which will update my text ui when the player collides with a diamond but I do not know how as I auto generate the diamonds

How could I go about writing a script that will update the text score

What I tried so far, but I'm not sure where to place it. (taken from comment)

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) { 
   if (other.CompareTag("Diamind")) {
      Debug.Log("Picking up..."); 
      GetComponent<Counter>().ScoreAmount += 1;
   } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Diamind")) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Picking up...");
        GetComponent<Counter>().ScoreAmount += 1;
    }  
}

Comment: That looks like a workable solution. What went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: well I get confused as where to put it

Comment: Where did you try putting it? Show that detail in your question, including a description of what goes wrong with the places you've tried so far.

Comment: And just to be sure, your tag is written as well with the spelling mistake and not just in your script, right?